# GWT: How to properly include a class in my module file?

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT 2.4.  My main EntryPoint class uses a Serializable class I've created, com.myco.clearing.common.xml.XmlNode.  How do I properly include that class in my .gwt.xml module that my EntryPoint class is using?  I tried including this in my .gwt.xml file ...

```
<inherits name='com.myco.clearing.common.xml.XmlNode'/>
```

but get this error when running my web application ...

```
     [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/myco/clearing/common/xml/XmlNode.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

Any way to properly include this class without having to change its package name? - Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have a gwt.xml file on your classpath as well as the source code (the .java file, gwt works with java code not class files)

The interits tag points to your gwt.xml file not to any class.

Inside the .gwt.xml file you can declare which packages gwt should see on its "classpath":

```
<module>
<source path="xml"/>

</module>
```

XmlNode can only uses classes that are compatible with gwt (e.g. no File or Sockets)